# Selenium for loop printing the same value each time

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through a list of events for every game and retrieve the minute that the event occured using a for loop.

However, my loop keeps printing the same value and I'm not sure why. When I print i.text, my code works as expected, but when I try to retrieve the minute using xpath, I keep receiving the first value.

What I expected

```
27
37
39
```

What I get

```
27
27
27
```

My code

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.forebet.com/en/football-predictions/predictions-1x2/2021-07-02")
    driver.maximize_window()


    games = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "rcnt")]')


    for x in games:
        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x.find_element_by_class_name("l_scr"))
            time.sleep(1)       
            events = x.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "lscr_main")]')

            for i in events:
                print(i.text)
                print(i.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "lscr_min")]').text)

            x.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@onclick, "scoreEvents")]')


        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the sleep time to 60 and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    driver.get("https://www.forebet.com/en/football-predictions/predictions-1x2/2021-07-02")
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//b[@class='l_scr']")
    # Tried only for 1st 5 elements
    for i in range(5):
        elements[i].click()
        minv = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='scoreEvents']//div[@class='lscr_min']")
        for val in minv:
            print(val.text)
        time.sleep(2)
```

And output was

```
    39'
    46'
    46'
    70'
    72'
    72'
```

so on.